# pgpool2 setup on master-slave replication using postgreql 9.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgpool

I have already setup 2 ubuntu server 12.04 LTS on my local machine using virtual box and is using the master-slave replication (postgresql 9.1).

1. 192.168.0.109 = master
2. 192.168.0.110 = slave

my question is how to apply the load-balancing based on the two database server? I've heard about pgpool2 and pgbouncer, which one should I use?

Thanks guys and sorry I am new to postgres replication.

Answer (score 2):

Of PgBouncer and PgPool-II, only PgPool-II supports load balancing.

PgPool-II's load balancing supports only read-only queries that meet certain requirements; see [the pgpool docs](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html). Additionally, if you start load-balancing queries you are no longer guaranteed to get a consistent view of the database because the replica might be lagging behind the master.

Personally, I'd look into adding a caching layer (memcached / Redis) before doing fiddly things like read-query load balancing.